# Accessing Routes in a MenuContainer

Tags: piral

I use piral for our micro-frontend app. I created a layout and use things like `<Menu>` in the layout.

I want to filter the entries in the nav menu by routes. Via convention i'll drop menu items depending on teh current route.

I only have one issue: how can I get access to the current route in the `MenuContainer`?

```
function Menu(props: MenuContainerProps) {
  const currentRoute = /* where to get it from?? */
  return /* my code */;
}
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piral just uses `react-router-dom` under the hood. Actually, this gives you access to anything from `react-router` and `react-router-dom`. As such hooks such as `useHistory` work in *all* components, e.g., your `Layout`, `MenuContainer`, or in *any* component of some pilet.

Example:

```
import { useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

const Menu = (props: MenuContainerProps) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const currentRoute = location.pathname;
  return /* my code */;
}
```

Hope that helps!